# Powersehll - Implement loging for failed attempt servers?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

**Requirement** : The below code will provide the instance name and database details & database states from the list of instances or servers available in `SQL_Servers.txt` from the path `C:\PowerSQL\`.

For few servers its not able to connect & throwing the error. I would like to keep these failed attempt server names in separate text file as Log.txt.

```
ForEach ($instance in Get-Content "C:\PowerSQL\SQL_Servers.txt") 
{ 
    Import-Module SQLPS -DisableNameChecking 
    Invoke-SQLcmd -Server $instance -Database master 'select @@servername as InstanceName,name as DatabaseName,state_desc as DBStatus from sys.databases' | Format-Table       
}
```

Help on this is highly appreciated.

Comment: The question is VERY similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39470677/how-to-write-powershell-script-to-list-the-available-databases-from-multiple-ser), even code... See my answer there, it might help [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39471534/2893376) just change `wtite-host` part, to write in log file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.That code will be helpful to list all the server details in a domain but I need only few listed server details specified in sql_server.txt . I need error details to be saved in log.csv or log.txt and the correct details into separated file.

Comment: You are kidding, right? Instead of domain check, just use your file, instead of write-host, write in log.txt. That's all.

Comment: I am not kidding gofr1 but I am trying to learn powershell.Please help.

Comment: There are 2 rows to change in answer I gave you link to. 2 rows. And I mentioned both of them in my comments here. Please, take a look, change them and here it is - an answer to your question!

Comment: Write-Log -Message "error when running Invoke-SQLcmd "+$instance -Path $LogFileName -Level Error . This command is not exporting the results anywhere.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124109/discussion-between-franklin-and-gofr1).

Answer (score 0):

the below code is full filled my requirement.

```
Import-Module SQLPS -DisableNameChecking
ForEach ($instance in Get-Content "C:\PowerSQL\SQL_Servers.txt") 
{
try { 
Invoke-SQLcmd -Server $instance -Database master 'select @@servername as InstanceName,name as DatabaseName,state_desc as DBStatus from sys.databases' 

$results += New-Object PSObject -Property $instanceinfo 

} catch { 
Add-Content "C:\PowerSQL\ErrorLog.txt" $instance
} 
} 

$results | export-csv -Path C:\PowerSQL\SQLServerInstance.csv -NoTypeInformation
```